# How to convert a date that's in local time to UTC in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift2, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Let's say I have a string in local time: "Apr 14, 2015, 8:53 AM". How can a convert that to the correct UTC time?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
let dateString = "Apr 14, 2015, 8:53 AM"
let df = NSDateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "LLL DD, yyyy, h:mm a"
if let dateFromString = df.dateFromString(dateString){
    print(dateFromString)  // "2015-01-14 10:53:00 +0000\n"
    df.timeZone = NSTimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)
    let stringFromDate = df.stringFromDate(dateFromString) //"Jan 14, 2015, 10:53 AM"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure but if you have a date string like 2014-07-15 06:55:14.198000+00:00 you can use this code

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = 
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(/*your_date_string*/)
```

Comment: Looks like you're just trying to create a date from a string. I'm trying to convert a string that represents "local time" into a string that's in UTC.